# thunderbird mark as read

Tags: thunderbird

In the old Eudora, it was possible to browse incoming messages without them being marked as "read". This is also possible in Thunderbird by unchecking the option "automatically mark messages as read".
However, in Eudora they would then automatically be marked as "read" by double-clicking to open the message. Is it possible to do this in Thunderbird?

Thunderbird version 11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Just at a guess (I used to use Eudora myself back in the day), you probably want to set automatically mark messages as read to be on, but set it to only do so after display of say, 35 seconds, and use the preview pane (if you aren't already using it that is) to allow for quick browsing of emails without triggering the read status.

This setup will make it so your message will be marked as read as soon as you open OPEN it (double click or pressing enter to open), but if you are just scrolling through and seeing it in the preview pane you could dwell on it for up to 35s before it thinks you've spent long enough, and therefore, have read it (you can also toggle that pane with F8 for a smidge more control)

You can find it at `Preferences > Display > Advanced` (current version is TB 52.8).